# Backlink To Post Ratio

Tags: seo, backlinks

Do backlinks to post ratio play a role in rankings?

Example

I have 100+ posts, (increasing each day) I only have 7 backlinks, however, those backlinks are from very high authority domains, with some of my blog posts being mentioned and linked by NY Times & NZ Herald amongst others.

My backlink to post ratio is less than 1/10 so am I wrong to think the more posts I am writing which are not getting links are diluting my current link value? Is this a case of less is more?

**EDIT A BIT MORE INFO**

According to MOZ opensiteexplorer, one penalty indication is:

> Large Site with Few Links
>   We found very few sites linking to this site, considering its size.

Here is the thing I don't care about backlinks, I write high quality long form content (2000-words+) some gets picked up and linked like my post in the NY Times and the NZ Herald, but I'm not going to spend ANY time building links or asking for guest posts, I'm letting content discovery happen naturally, thus my question considering amount of content to small number of backlinks ratio but from HIGH authority domains is MOZ right with the penalty trigger "warning"?

Comment: OK,@JohnConde can you perhaps give me some info, advice on question?

Comment: My advice is not to put any stock in third party SEO tools

Comment: Yeah I know that - and I'm certainly not paying for any crappy service, it just stirred my curiosity, on the subject...

Comment: Did you mean to say you get fewer than 10 backlinks per post? That doesn't seem particularly low. Or did you mean that your backlink-to-post ration is less than *1/10*?

Comment: When I first read this question, I took it as outbound links from your page and **not** inbound (back) links to any page. My answer is for outbound links and not inbound links. Can you confirm that you mean inbound (back) links or outbound links (from your page to other sites)? If you mean back links, I will either delete or adjust my answer. I will also be majorly bummed because my answer is pretty good even if it is completely wrong! ;-) Ooopppsss! Sorry. It has been a crazy day. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Question was: "Do backlinks to post ratio play a role in rankings?"

My understanding is that other factors play a far bigger role than backlinks to your site in ranks. Backlinks are well down in the food chain. Yes, good quality ones are a benefit so good to have.

I would look to the traffic on your site. Is it good/satisfactory? Is it engaged by your high quality 2000+ words? If yes, then carry on as you are.

Are the pages with the backlinks to them performing considerably better than other pages in engagement/conversion terms? The answer to that question might help you decide what's best for your site.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Adding posts do your blog doesn't dilute your site value in any way. As long as you are adding quality content, it will never hurt your site to add a reasonable amount more.  The only times that adding to your site will hurt is when it is low quality or excessive (tens of thousands).

The ratio of back links to posts isn't something to which Google pays any attention.  Google uses a metric called [Pagerank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) to determine page reputation.  Some ways in which it is different than your back-links to pages ratio:

- It isn't just just the number of back-links that counts.   Back links from high reputation pages count more.
- Each page contributes some initial value.   This means that new pages actually *help* rather than hurt.

Google has tweaked its algorithms and added a lot of factors since they announced PageRank nearly 20 years ago.   However they still use Pagerank internally and they wouldn't replace it with a simplistic metric like your ratio.

A few years ago it was good SEO to "sculpt" Pagerank.   That is adjust the internal links on your site to push the link juice to the pages that needed help with rankings.   Google made a bunch of changes to make that practice less successful.   These days I don't know any sites that chalk their high rankings up to how well they optimize the topography of pages and links.

In short, don't worry too much about how adding content is going to affect the metrics that Google uses.   If adding content would be good for your users, then do so.   In the near term it probably won't hurt SEO, especially not in any way you can actually measure.   In the long term it will certainly help SEO because your new quality content will attract more links.

Answer (score 1):

There are no any kind of ratio and such thing, Google just do calculation on their metric, for example PR calculation, Domain Authority Calculation(Not moz one), Trust rank(Who author links to you) etc.

What I want to add here is, there are thousand of website now start participation in blackhat technique, for example they hire some journalist or writter to add their website link on top media website like huffingtonpost, NYT, mashable etc.

Just search on Google, and you can also buy such a links on those website for $500 or $1000.  That is purely bad things, I know the owner or webmaster can't check all the articles and see weather links are bad or not, but Google can know about that.

**Google have pretty clear algorithm which can makes any links value zero**. And they can know by checking your anchor text, and little more by doing spying. I really have no idea about how they do spy, but I have seen some of dead webpages(Who allowed to add dofollow links) where hundred of webmaster put their rich keyword anchor text, and Google just simply ignore them in calculation.

Pay more attention on what Stephen said.

> Each page contributes some initial value. This means that new pages
>   actually help rather than hurt.

The thing is thing is that, if links are purely natural, then there is nothing you should worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish quality content that values more in Google point of view. Don't create quantity of backlinks but quality of links that give boost to your website and increase search ranking also.